# Get multiple objects in one query in Django

Tags: python, django

I have 3 models:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20, null=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)

class Attachment(models.Model):
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='attachments/')

class Comment(models.Model):
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField(null=False)
```

In my views.py file in want to process all of them, so in order to get them I perform 3 queries:

```
tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(id=ticket_id)
attachments = Attachment.objects.filter(ticket=ticket_id)
comments = Comment.objects.filter(ticket=ticket.id)
```

I want to hit database just once, so my question is how can I get them in one query? I have read about [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) method, but **Attachment** and **Comment** models are not related directly to each other, so I can't start query from any of them. From the other hand **Ticket** model doesn't have fields like **attachment** or **comment** so I can't start query from it.

Comment: I think it's impossible to generate one query for 3 models unless the relationship is declared to the first called object.

Comment: How about chain method? You could do something like results=chain(tickets, attachments, comments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using [prefetch related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related), example:

Note: you have to add related to the foreign key.

```
# models.py    
class Attachment(models.Model):
        ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='attachment')
        file = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='attachments/')
    
    class Comment(models.Model):
        ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Comment')
        comment = models.TextField(null=False)


#your query

from django.db.models import Prefetch
    
    tickets = Ticket.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('attachment', to_attr='ticket_attachment'), Prefetch('comment', to_attr='ticket_comment'))

print(ticket.first().ticket_attachment.all())
```